# How do I dynamically generate maps with Leaflet.js?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps

I'm trying to implement maps into a website using Leaflet.js, but I've ran into a problem. Every tutorial I can find passes an ID to the Leaflet map function, like this:

In HTML:

```
<div id="mapid"></div>
```

In JavaScript:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
```

The website I'm working on has a search function which queries a database and then returns a list of matching organizations. Most (but not all!) organizations have an address associated with it, and I'm trying to generate a map for each address.

So, I can't have a single div with an ID (because I need multiple divs), and I can't just name them "map1", "map2", "map3", etc. because it's dynamic: the number of maps needed is different each time.

Right now, in the search result template I have a map div with a CLASS of "map", but I can't get Leaflet to work with this.

How can I get Leaflet to work in this situation (using a class instead of an ID)?

Comment: So? Fetch the organizations' IDs as well, and create each `<div>` with a DOM ID based on each organization's ID. Stuff doesn't need to be numerically consecutive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Leaflet documentation shows that the 1st argument of `L.map` factory can be directly an HTML Element (instead of a string representing the Element ID):

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-l-map

> `L.map(<HTMLElement> el, <Map options> options?)`
>
> Instantiates a map object given an instance of a `<div>` HTML element

That way, you do not have to choose any unique ID, and just build your map with the Element you just created.